# Nunito & Open Sans fonts are not working in inline css for email template

Tags: css, email, fonts

I have created email template using table tags with font (Nunito & Open Sans) from google import.

Here is my code...

```
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,300,400,600,700,800,900|Open+Sans:300,400,600,700,800&display=swap');
</style>
```

Using like this way...

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="style="font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; font-size:25.84px; color:#000; text-align:center; font-weight:600;"">
         Welcome Text
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The above code is working in my local fine. but when I have sent email fonts are not applying.

Comment: What email client are you testing in? `@font-face` support is limited: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/font-face/

Comment: You also have an error in your inline style declaration: `<td style="style="..."">`

Comment: https://jangomail.com/

Comment: this I have paste mistake.

<td style="style="font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; font-size:25.84px; color:#000; text-align:center; font-weight:600;""> 

In my local its like this... 
<td style="font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; font-size:25.84px; color:#000; text-align:center; font-weight:600;">

Comment: Email _client_, ie. the software that you use to view the email. Is it Outlook? Apple Mail? Gmail iOS App?  etc. Did you look at the link I posted? Is font-face supported by your email client?